# Exibir botão após submit da página oracle apex

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Tenho uma página de teste em https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=43921:2 usuário test senha test, que já funcionando ok, em geral. Ela faz a migração de empregados usando um objeto shuttle, e utilizando collections para atualizar as informações. Até aí tudo bem. Ocorre que não quero deixar habilitado, ou exibir o botão de migração, quando eu remover todos os itens da coleção, que são alimentados no shuttle. 
No shuttle a cada alteração eu retroalimento a collection e ao final eu a resequencio, sabendo que se houver pelo menos um registro dessa collection haverá ao menos um seq_id igual a 1.
Criei uma pequena validação como essa:

```
declare
vazio NUMBER;
begin
select 1 into vazio from dual 
INTERSECT
select seq_id  from apex_collections col where collection_name = 'COLECAO_POSTOS_EMPREGADOS'; 

    if vazio  = 1 then
        RETURN TRUE;
    END IF;    
    EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       RETURN FALSE;
end;
```

Adicionei uma dynamic action no change do shuttle executando, que faz um submitt page, ao retornar verdadeira essa condição. E criei uma server-side-condition, no botão de migração. Só que quando eu carrego o shuttle o botão não é exibido. Como o submit tem essa função de dar ao servidor novas informações do cliente, não entendi porque o botão não foi exibido. Acho que minha tentativa foi um tanto mirabolante, também. Alguém tem alguma outra solução de como mostra/esconder ou habilitar/desabilitar o botão, com os recursos do SHUTTLE?

Obrigado